# Settings icon for self has wrong title

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

The new settings icon on a team page you are a member of has the wrong title:

[image: “remove poke from sopython”]

It suggests that clicking it would remove myself from the team, when it actually just opens a popup where I can also change my team role.

Comment: This is on our list to fix. Should be done soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build.